# Django - save AxesSubplot via seaborn to django models.ImageField

Tags: python, django, seaborn

I'm trying to save graph from seaborn module as *ImageField* to django model.

**models.py**

```
class HeatmapFiles(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(
        'CustomUser',
        verbose_name='Username',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False
    )
    heatmap = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name='Heatmap',
        blank=False
    )
```

I've tried to save via *ImageFile*:

**example_file.py**

```
import io
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

sns.set()
flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
new = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5, ax=ax)

figure = io.BytesIO()
new.get_figure().savefig(figure, format='png')
image_file = ImageFile(figure.getvalue())
```

and **image_file** objects returns **None** here:

```
<ImageFile: None>
```

I can save it, but that doesn't make sense.
How to save *"new"* heatmap object as django model?

UPD: 
after `new.get_figure().savefig(figure, format='png')` **figure.getvalue()** actually **HAS** data **"b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00...."** inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're defining `figure` as empty bytesIO and put that in `image_file = ImageFile(...)`, so image_file returns None. Besides, `new.get_figure().savefig(...)` save png file separately.

To save "new" heapmap object as django model.

1. `new.get_figure().savefig` save file as you like.
2. Using that file path in `models.ImageField`, then a file will be uploaded to django.

Ps: you need () as get_figure(), I think.